# If $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$,then $f(1)-f(0)=\dfrac {f'(x)}{2x}$ has at least one solution in $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the following problem that says:

> If $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$,then show by Cauchy's M.V.T. (or otherwise) that the equation $f(1)-f(0)=\dfrac {f'(x)}{2x}$ has at least one solution in $(0,1)$.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from the [statement of the theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem) for the case $g(x) = x^2$ you have
$$
  2x(f(1) - f(0)) = f'(x)
$$
for some $x \in (0,1)$. Since $x>0$, the answer to your question immediately follows.

Answer (score 0):

The function $g$ defined by $g(x)=f(x)-x^2(f(1)-f(0))$ is such that $g(1)=f(0)=g(0)$ hence by the mean value theorem (more specifically, [Rolle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)), there exists $x$  in $(0,1)$ such that $g'(x)=0$. But, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, $g'(x)=$ $____$, hence you are done.